# Custom header file implementation

Tags: c

I have a custom header file example.h which has prototypes for a few functions. There is a .C file example.c that I implemented which "includes" (#include "example.h") and has the implementations of the functions that has prototype in example.h.

Now, I have another function test.c that has to call the functions that are prototyped in example.h and are implemented in example.c. How Can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Just `#include "example.h"` in `test.c` (and don't forget to link all of the object files!)

Answer (score 1):

You need to link them all at the end (assuming you have already included the prototypes into your `test.c`). So if you're compiling, you can compile both of the `.c` files together into one executable. More commonly, however, is to compile these without linking (which produces object files). Then, at the end, link all of the object files together. To do this depends on your compiler, but an example would be:

```
gcc -c -o example.o example.c
gcc -c -o test.o test.c
gcc -o my_application test.o example.o
```

Or, for a small project, this works just as well

```
gcc -o my_application example.c test.c
```